# Android - What started my service?

Tags: android, android-service

I have a service that I use to upload selected files while the user is off doing other things. It starts when my application tells it to, and it stops when my app tells it to. But for some reason I get my service starting notification at seemingly random times when using other apps. Is there a way to determine what told my service to start?

It is standard service in that it extends Service, and is bound to my UploadScreenActivity.

The onCreate is pretty simple:

```
public void onCreate() {
    instance = this;
    if(connectivityManager == null){
            connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    }
    mNM = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Service started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And that 'service started' notification appears at seemingly random times while navigating other applications.

The code for my service is based off of the local service sample in the Service doc: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: your question is yet not clear... can you please share your code?

Answer (score 0):

The system will not start your service on its own.  Does the app listen for anything externally in broadcast receivers?  If not, you must be starting it in your code somewhere.  I'd beef up the logging and keep an eye on it.  Alternatively post an event to an error logging service (bugsense, acra, etc).

What parts of your code start the service?  I'd start there.  Occam's razor.

Answer (score 0):

have you defined an intent filter for your service that gives allows other apps to start your Service implicitly.
Also this reference from android devlopers might help:
android:exported
Whether or not components of other applications can invoke the service or interact with it — "true" if they can, and "false" if not. When the value is "false", only components of the same application or applications with the same user ID can start the service or bind to it.